# assembler program (TASM) calculate raise m to the power of n (m^n)

Tags: assembly, x86

I have already coded half of the program. The problem is I don't know how to code math operation part is raise `m` to the power of `n (m^n)`. So, any advise for me as a beginner?

```
.MODEL SMALL

.DATA

greet   db 13,10, "Welcome to Simple Calculator: Raise m to the power n. $"
msg1    db 13,10, 0AH,0DH,"Please enter integer (m:-99 to 99): $"
m       db 3,4 dup(?)
msg2    db 10,13, 0AH,0DH,"Please enter power (n:1 to 9): $"
n       db 3,4 dup(?)
total   db 10,13, "Answer: $"


.CODE

START:

mov ax, seg greet
mov ds, ax
mov dx, offset greet
mov ah, 09h     ;Display message
int 21h 

mov ax, seg msg1
mov ds, ax
mov dx, offset msg1
mov ah, 09h
int 21h         ;Print a message

mov ah, 0ah
mov dx, offset m
int 21h         ;Get 'm' value


n_POWER:

mov ax, seg msg2
mov ds, ax
mov dx, offset msg2
mov ah, 09h
int 21h         ;Print a message

mov ah, 0ah
mov dx, offset n    ;Get 'n' value
int 21h

mov ax, m
mov n, ax
mul ax, n
mov total, n

finish:
mov ah, 09h ;Display message
int 21h

mov ax,4c00h    ;Return control to DOS
int 21h         
end start
```

Also, how can I get the negative input from the user (eg. `-99`) ?

Comment: do i need to use "JMP" commands?

Comment: Related: [function Power(x,y) in assembly ia32 max 32 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53341606) for the standard O(log2(n)) integer power algorithm using multiplying and shifting.  (Like for implementing multiply in terms of shift-and add, but exponentiation in terms of multiply.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either repeat the multiplication as in:

```
int result = 1;  while (exp-->0) { result *= base; } return result;
```

or, you can / should treat the exponent in it's binary representation:

```
5^13 = 5^(0b1101) = 1*(5^1)*(5^4)*(5^8)
```

One can thus repeatedly *square* a copy of the base 5: 5 -> 25 -> 625 -> 390625 and multiply those terms that have a corresponding bit set in the binary representation of the exponent.

This may be overkill for 16-bit arithmetic, but it'll be handy if your professor asks you to perform a modular exponentation instead (as used in asymmetric cryptography).

Both methods require using *conditional* jumps:

to conditionally repeat `cx` number of operations one simply does:

```
         mov cx, 13
label:   nop  // put your block of code here
         nop
         loop label;  // The instruction at label will be executed 13 times
         // and cx will end up being zero
```

To test a bit being set, one can do

```
         mov dx, 13      ;; let's have the exponent here
label:   test dx, 1      ;; check if the first bit is zero
                         ;; test performs bitwise _and_ between the operand
                         ;; and sets ZERO flag (among other things)
         jz   notset     
         nop             ;; insert here the statements to be executed
                         ;; when the bit in the exponent is set
notset:  shr dx, 1       ;; shift out the least significant bit -- this also
                         ;; sets the ZERO_FLAG if dx goes to zero
                         ;; (and it eventually does)
         jne label;      ;;
```

btw. JNE == Jump if Not Equal also tests for zero flag.
It's synonymous to Jump if Not Zero.

Comment: yes, thank you for your help. But, why i must use looping 13 times? can '13' be replaced  by 'n' for power?

Comment: Yes, you can and should replace the constant with your variable. Also you should fill in the instructions performing the multiplication and squaring. This is by no means a complete block of code to be copy-pasted, as this would defeat the purpose of learning.

Comment: if i want to put input for eg. '-99' , how should i do? i must convert those thing in binary? or any other way?

Comment: Please make that a separate question. (Or even preferably try the find an assembler primer, which has a chapter about integer representation, base conversions and input/output of numbers). I'm sure the FAQ section of assembler tag in SO is also full of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Computing integer powers is just a series of multiplications. For example, 5^2 == 5*5, 2^3 == 2*2*2, and so on.

Hence, a simple multiplying loop will suffice:

```
mov bx,5   ; m
mov cx,3   ; n
mov ax,1   ; Initial result, i.e. m^0
power:
    jcxz power_done
    mul bx
    loop power
power_done:
; ax now contains m^n
```

Note that my example code doesn't handle cases where the result grows larger than 16 bits (except implicitly on the last iteration). It also doesn't handle negative values for `m`. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to look up the instruction set reference for ways to fix those things if you need them.

Comment: Why do you need jcxz (and if it's for generic case, why is it inside the loop block?)

Comment: To make a self-contained loop block which handles all inputs >= 0. The question wasn't about the fastest way of calculating powers (in that case the OP should just use a modern C/C++ compiler and call it a day).

Comment: mean that, i can substitute constant '5' with 'm'?

Comment: Wait. `m` and `n` are input buffers for `int 21h/0Ah`. Input text starts at `n + 2` and `m + 2`... and it's a text representation of a number, not a number you can do arithmetic on.

Comment: @FrankKotler: Correct. `m` and `n` are assumed to be integers, since the question was how to perform the `power` operation. If the inputs are strings they'd have to be converted to integers beforehand, but that would be a separate question.

Comment: `jcxz` doesn't need to be inside the loop.  See [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47783926) for normal loop structure to handle the case where the count may be zero.