# Simulating left shift micro instruction

Tags: assembly, exponential

I’m trying to simulate left shift micro instruction in scpu-sim , using assembly language .

‘M about to multiply the value by 2^n , 
But I’m stuck in how to actually represent 2^n ?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916733/assembler-program-tasm-calculate-raise-m-to-the-power-of-n-mn) SO question.

Comment: @JeroenHeier that's about power. Here the OP is asking about shifting. Moreover he didn't use x86

Comment: @Rota a left shift can be simulated by adding to itself. In C `x <<= 1` can be done by `x *= 2` or `x += x`