# How to raise a number to a power in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, tasm, dosbox

So i have two variables a and b and I need to raise a to the power b in assembly code.

I know I can do this by multiplying a by b times in a loop (it only needs to work on 16 bits) but I dont know how to do it with variables.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Looping a variable number of times is about the same as looping a constant number of times.

Comment: [function Power(x,y) in assembly ia32 max 32 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53341606) has a 32-bit implementation using inputs in registers. (  You could obviously load your inputs into registers to start with.)  It uses `cmov` and IDK if TASM supports a `.686` option to enable PPro instructions, otherwise you'd have to port it to use a branch.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ok but whats the difference when u loop a variable and when u loop a constant, because if I try to do it the same way as I would loop a constant it gives me an error.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong :P but you haven't shown how you tried to do it.  A normal loop with `mov si, var` ahead of the loop, and  `dec si` / `jnz looptop` at the bottom, works fine whether for a variable, another register, or an immediate constant.  Pick any convenient register, doesn't have to be `si`.

Comment: @PeterCordes So this is how i tried to do it

`.DATA
a db 3,4
b db 3,4

.CODE
START:

mov ah, 0ah
mov dx, offset a ;a
int 21h         

mov ah, 0ah
mov dx, offset b    ;b
int 21h

add bl,a
add cl,b
mov bx,'5'   ; a
mov cx,'2'   ; b
mov ax,'1'   ; Initial result, i.e. m^0
power:
    jcxz power_done
    mul bx
    loop power
power_done:
; ax now contains m^n`

And the error I get is Operand types do not match
Sorry I cant make it look ok on the website

Comment: [edit] your question if you want to post an attempt and turn this into a debugging question, with a [mcve] including which line produced that error.  (You don't need `jcxz` *inside* a loop, only optionally ahead of the loop.  That's not a correctness problem, though, just performance.)